# How do you group an array via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I group the array via javascript to just

- Vehicles
- Food

I can't figure it out via "reduce" since the array has no "key" to specify.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't get your question completely, but if you are trying to remove duplicates, this could be an option

```js
const originalArray = ["vehicle", "food", "vehicle", "food", "vehicle", "food"];
const noDuplicates = new Set(originalArray);
console.log(Array.from(noDuplicates));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const group1 = arr.filter(item => item === 'Vehicles');
const group2 = arr.filter(item => item === 'Food');
```

Or if you want a general solution:

```
let groups = {};
for (const item of arr) {
  if (!groups[item]) groups[item] = [];
  groups[item].push(item);
}
```